# javascript sort array of arrays based on min-max position

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array looks like this(each row is an array) :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I am trying to sort it using first row-last row alternately until middle row is reached.
Expected

```
1 2 3
7 8 9
4 5 6
```

Another example on larger array(r,c always equal,elems are unique) :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 =>

1 2 3 4
13 14 15 16
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

I can make it into an object and use objectKeys to sort it but is there a better solution?

Comment: At least to me it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "sort" if your operation doesn't depend on actual array **content**. If you just shuffle elements around in a prescribed way then call it "reorder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, I think this is one solution for your question

```js
var x = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
  ],
  f = 0,
  r = x.length - 1,
  output = [];

while (f <= r) {
  output.push(x[f++]);
  if (f > r) {
    break;
  }
  output.push(x[r--])
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yes,this is it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't unambiguously figure out your algorithm, but I suggest that you use Arrays instead of Objects, since they are cut out for this kind of data. Specifically, you can represent your data as a 2-dimensional Array (array of arrays).

```
[
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
    [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
    [ 13, 14, 15, 16 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop...

```
function my_reorder(L) {
    result = [];
    let i=0, j=L.length-1;
    while (i <= j) {
        result.push(L[i++]);
        if (i <= j) result.push(L[j--]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

at each iteration one element is taked from the top going down and another from the bottom going up. The second check inside the loop is because the number of elements in the original array may be even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple recursive pattern:

- Check if Array has items,

  - If yes, pick first and last item.
  - If elements exists, push to `result`.
  - Repeat the process for remainder array.
- If not, return a blank array and stop.

**Note:** `array.shift`, `array.pop` will mutate original array. So make sure, you send a copy of `data` if you do not need any side-effect

```js
function sortInOrder(arr) {
  if(arr.length === 0) return [];
  var result = [];
  var first = arr.shift();
  var last = arr.pop()
  if(!!first) result.push(first);
  if(!!last)  result.push(last);
  result = result.concat(sortInOrder(arr));
  return result;
}

var data = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
    [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
    [ 13, 14, 15, 16 ],
    [ 17, 18, 19, 20]
];

console.log(sortInOrder(data))
```

**A hackish way**

Use recursion with pop and shift. This will not handle odd values as suggested by @[Nikhil Aggarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132354/nikhil-aggarwal). For this, you can set result's length to input array's length and you should be good.

```js
function sortInOrder(arr) {
  var length = arr.length;
  if(length === 0) return [];
  var result = [].concat([ arr.shift() ], [ arr.pop() ], sortInOrder(arr));
  result.length = length;
  return result;
}

var data = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
    [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
    [ 13, 14, 15, 16 ],
    [ 17, 18, 19, 20]
];

console.log(sortInOrder(data))
```

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Great observation sir. I have updated the post to handle odd number length as well. Hope it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try following using a for loop

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];

let result = [];
for(let i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j/2; i++) {
  result.push(arr[i]);
  if(j - i - 1 > i) result.push(arr[j - i - 1]);
}
console.log(result);
```